# Как восстановить .MYD файл?

Tags: mysql

Всем привет, случилась очень не хорошая ситуация, после отключения света на одном из серверов сломалась БД, в частности 2е таблицы.
Попытка восстановления через MysqlAdministrator  не дала результатов.
Программа ругается на то, что файл таблицы  физически отсутствует.
Хотя в каталоге с БД он есть, даже размер указан. Таблица.MYD копировать/удалять/открывать  файл себя не дает

> Ошибка чтения файла, файл поврежден или используется другим процессом.

Как оживить эти таблички, кто что подскажет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, если у вас есть бекап этих табличек, просто отключите сервис mysql в linux. Это делается через `sudo service mysql stop` в виндовс  `sc stop MySQL` или как он у вас там называется. Потом попробуйте скопировать таблички. Вообще для начала попробовали бы  `mysqlcheck -c имябазы таблица -u логин -p пароль`.

Comment: Проблема была глубже) Хард накрылся.